# Mapping SQL rows to nested structs/slices in Go

Tags: sql, go

I'm having a hard time mapping the returned rows with a one-to-many relationship to a nested struct in Go.

The struct looks like:

```
type Result struct {
    ID         string      `db:"id" json:"id"`
    Title      string      `db:"title" json:"title"`
    Content    string      `db:"content" json:"content"`
    TableA    []TableA   `json:"tablea"`
}

type TableA struct {
    foo       string `db:"foo" json:"foo"`
    bar       string `db:"bar" json:"bar"`
    TableAId  string `db:"tablea_id" json:"tablea_id"`
}
```

The corresponding tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tablea (
  id INT (10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR (55) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE tableb (
  id INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  foo VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  bar VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  tablea_id INT (10) UNSIGNED,
  INDEX par_ind (tablea_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tablea_id) REFERENCES tablea(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

I can't figure out how to map the rows of

```
SELECT
         tablea.id, tablea.title, tablea.content,
         tableb.foo, tableb.bar
       FROM gowebapp.tablea
       LEFT OUTER JOIN gowebapp.tableb On tableb.tablea_id = tablea.id;
```

with the return

```
+----+-------+---------+------+------+
| id | title | content | foo  | bar  |
+----+-------+---------+------+------+
|  1 | lorem | ipsum   | foo1 | bar1 |
|  1 | lorem | ipsum   | foo2 | bar2 |
|  1 | lorem | ipsum   | foo3 | bar3 |
+----+-------+---------+------+------+
```

to my Result struct. I'm new to Go and tried to make the examples above as generic as possible as I haven't found any resources on how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For that what you want to do maybe a SQL DB is not the optimal DB-type. So I would select tablea and select tableb and range over the results to build my result struc

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for your reply!